# How requestAnimationFrame() works?

Tags: javascript

```
var balls = [];

function loop() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    while(balls.length < 1) {
        var ball = new Ball();
        balls.push(ball);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        balls[i].draw();
        balls[i].update();
        balls[i].collisionDetect();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
}

loop();
```

When this code is run for the first time as the draw() method completes the ball appears on the canvas and then the update() updates the value of x, y co-ordinate of the ball and then the requestAnimationFrame() calls the loop() method again but, this time when the draw() method completes, the position of the ball is not updated immediately instead the ball position is updated in the next call to requestAnimationFrame()

Something like this is happening in the code
please explain what exactly is happening?

and how requestAnimationFrame() works?

the full code: https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/javascript/oojs/bouncing-balls/main-finished.js

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) explains it quite well